Protecting wood around undermount sink
Bought a flipped house. First picture below is an overview of the kitchen right after we bought it showing the sink area.  Next three are close up of the sink from today, after about two months of use.  It appears that there is some kind of black paint that is peeling away from the countertop.  You can see the pressboard / particleboard countertop in the areas where the black has peeled away.
What is my best option to repair this?  I've found discussions about sealing undermount "butcher block" sinks where the wood will look really nice once sealed.  But this is just particle board.  If I strip off this black paint and just put on some polyurethane, I know its not going to look good.  I'm considering an epoxy with a black pigment, but I've done that before so I don't know if it will turn out.  Other suggestions?
I'm aware of this question but without pictures I'm not sure if its relevant How do I protect wood countertops from kitchen sink?




**Edit Updates **
Thanks for the comments.  I'm going to be honest, I'm not 100% sure if this is laminate or epoxy.  Not familiar enough with the different options to distinguish.  Everything else in the rest of the house was done to "good enough" standards but not "luxury" standards, so I'd say its probably the cheaper laminate options.
I have resigned myself to the fact that this was probably a poor choice of sink for the counter and that it will probably have to be replaced eventually.  Hoping to get at least a year out of it though.
I did poke around more and find a discovery.  Two more pictures. One of the one side of the sink, you can see clear silicone between the sink and the countertop. On the other side, there is no silicone.  Literally nothing sealing the gap between the sink and the countergap.  So I'm guessing the water got in from the underneath, and that it was started causing this black stuff to peel off (still not sure what it is).
For now, I've applied silicone liberally in the areas where it was missing. It's still going to look bad, but it will stop it from deteriorating further while I can save up to have the sink replaced.



I will leave this as a comment, since it does not answer your question. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but the worst thing anybody could have done would be to use an undermount sink with a particle board countertop. There is no good real fixes for the long term just patching it until it is no longer bearable and the top is replaced. Perhaps there is a way, but all the undermounts I have seen and installed has been with solid wood in one fashion or another.

@Jack Not even solid wood - that also has issues with water. I usually (admittedly not a pro, so I only see what I see in friends' houses, etc.) more typically undermount sinks used with granite or other stone/stone-like surfaces that won't absorb water to any significant degree.

undermount can work with laminate (eg Formica(tm)).  What's the top surface here? is it laminate or some sort of epoxy?

I agree with Jack. This was a bad idea that will get worse.  It was an attempt to make a more attractive kitchen to give the home a greater appeal to buyers.  The black "stuff" was an attempt to seal the wood core of the countertop.  There is no reasonable way to make this work well in the long term.

Flippers doing flipper things—in this case, cheaping out on everything.  They used a particleboard counter because it's much cheaper than solid surface.  If they'd used a top-mount sink it may have lasted until the owner is ready to remodel.

Correctly installed the undermount sink would be glued to the laminate on the bench surface not to the wood. This might seem janky but it can last 30 years no problem, longer if you also support the sink.
Maybe you can get in there with a router and  cut the wood back so that the sink can be mounted correctly.
If the top surface is poured epoxy  you'll probably have to drop the sink in from above into a rebate cut to accept its flange
so that it sits just below the surface build a dam around the opening of the sink using tape and then re-epoxy the benchtop.

The countertop is plastic laminate.  I don't think anyone would use an expensive epoxy and then not fully epoxy and seal the edges of the sink opening.  This was a cheap attempt to add sales appeal to the home so it could be flipped quickly.

@RMDman that doesn't make Jasen wrong.  If the particleboard can be dried out, it's possible a top-mount sink can be (properly) installed and last until the owner is ready to remodel.

Dropping the sink into a routed out "rebate cut" and epoxying it, still does not make a proper mounting.  This is also assuming the counter is epoxy, which it is not.  The work is also approaching the point of negative return , in that one would just be better off removing the counter and installing a surface mounted sink.  But that is not what Jasen said.

if the top surface was poured epoxy there would be a decent chance for it to seal to a rebated sink.
